# how can I access my ustom attribute in the Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I use

POST https://graph.windows.net/contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6

to get the Information from users in my Azure AD B2C.

But how can I access my ustom attribute in the Azure AD B2C?

Thanks for your help
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your Azure AD schema in the same way you would your on-premises directory. The following page on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions) has some information on this for you.

You can also use the [Graph API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/03/05/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview/) to achieve this as well using a POST.

Specifically for Azure AD B2C, you can do this in the [portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try with B2CGraphClient, in this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/ you will find how you can see your custom attributes (see the last section)

Comment: Thanks. But I dont understand how I map the attributes to an application.